# Finding a cross section of a cube

Tags: geometry

I am given the following cube where points $A,B,C$ lie on the bottom, left and back face respectively.[image]

I know how to find cross sections when the points lie on the edges. But, in this case, I dont know how to start. Is there a useful trick to handle this type of problems? Thanks.

Comment: You are given the cube and 3 points. And? Would you clarify what cross section it is?

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ mid points of the faces?

Comment: Please explain how you solve when the points are on the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi$ be the plane of the triangle $ABC$. Drop perpendiculars from $B$ and $C$ to the bottom plane $\beta$, resulting in the auxiliary points $B'$,  $C'\in\beta$. The lines $B\vee C\subset \pi$ and $B'\vee C'\subset\beta$ intersect in the point $F\in(\pi\wedge\beta)$. It follows that the line $F\vee A$ is in fact $=\pi\wedge\beta$. In the situation of the following figure we now have enough material to construct the cross section we are after by connecting known points and intersecting with the proper edges. Depending on the given disposition the cross section could, e.g., be a hexagon. In such a case a second auxiliary step will be necessary.

[image]

Comment: Check the upper edge of the quadrilateral. It must end at the vertical edge of the back face.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thank you for spotting the slip. Hope it's correct now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want the cross-section given by the plane through $A$, $B$, $C$.

If so, first note that the plane normal is in the direction $(B-A)\times(C-A)$, so its equation can be written in the form
$$
(X - A) \cdot \big[ (B-A)\times(C-A)\big] = 0
$$
Intersect this plane with each face of the cube.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain his (or her) reasoning? Is the answer incorrect, unhelpful, presumptuous, offensive, or what? Just curious.